# Is there an app_fixture.php or behavior for CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, fixtures

I want to add a function that will be used by several fixtures in my app, and it would be nice to be able to put it somewhere reflecting that it's an extension to CakeTestFixture.  In a Model, I could do this by writing a Behavior or adding it to app_model.php.  Is there a way to do this for fixtures?

I can always just add it to my static Utility class, but it would be nice to be able to structure it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an `AppTestFixture` which extends `CakeTestFixture` and include it in there. Obviously each fixture then has to extend your new class instead of Cake's one.

Comment: That would work.  For now I think I'll stick with Utility, unless I start getting to crazy.